Does joint convexity imply separate convexity?
If $f(x,y)$ is jointly convex in $(x,y)$, does it imply that $f(x,y)$ is also convex separately in $x$ and $y$?
I know the converse is not true. But not sure if joint convexity implies separate convexity. I tried coming up with counterexamples. I considered
$x^2+y^2=10$. This is clearly convex in $(x,y)$. And if $y$ is fixed, we do get a convex function in $x$. I am not sure if this observation holds for any general function.

A more geometric way to see this is to note that $f$ is convex iff its epigraph is convex, and the epigraph restricted to a subspace (or an affine space) is still convex.

If $f(x, y)$ is jointly convex then for all $t \in [0, 1]$, $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and $v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2$
$$f(t v_1 + (1 - t) v_2) \leq t f(v_1) + (1 - t) f(v_2)$$
In particular, for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ we can choose $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $v_2 = \begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y \end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ which implies
$$f\left( \begin{bmatrix} t x_1 + (1 - t) x_2 \\ y \end{bmatrix} \right) = f\left( t \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y \end{bmatrix} + (1 - t) \begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y \end{bmatrix} \right) \leq t f\left( \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y \end{bmatrix} \right) + (1 - t) f\left( \begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y \end{bmatrix} \right)$$
so $f$ is indeed convex in $x$ for any fixed $y$. A similar argument can be used to show $f$ is convex in $y$ for any fixed $x$.
